# android implements OnListFragmentInteractionListener but not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

I have created a simple app with empty activity and then I created (by wizard) a FragmentList.

Afterthat I add implementation of OnListFragmentInteractionListener in activity, then I added a classic Toast to verify OnClick on DummyItems. It's all ok! Good.

Now, I changed model, and implement other things in my activity. Now OnListFragmentInteractionListener not working.

I created a secondo project with empty activity and fragmentlist, and I compared codes of two projects, about FragmentList implementation seems all ok.

Debugging I noted that onCreateView of Fragment.java mListener is null yet.
In my second project is instantiated instead. 
Have you got any idea where I have to search the problem?

```
public class OptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements DeviceBTFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);

    Typeface font_caption = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/univers_condensed_bold.ttf");
    TextView textView_caption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_fragment);
    textView_caption.setTypeface(font_caption);

}

@Override
public void onListFragmentInteraction(DeviceBT item) {
    //DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    //String message = Float.toString(metrics.density);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,item.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DeviceBTCardActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("DEVICE_NAME", item.name);
    intent.putExtra("DEVICE_ADDRESS",item.address);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class DeviceBTFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

private int mColumnCount = 1;
private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public DeviceBTFragment() { }

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static DeviceBTFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
    DeviceBTFragment fragment = new DeviceBTFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_devicebt_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new DeviceBTRecyclerViewAdapter(GetItems(), mListener));
    }

    return view;
}

private List<DeviceBT> GetItems()
{
    List<DeviceBT> mItems = new ArrayList<DeviceBT>();

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
    }
    else
    {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }

        int mIndex = 0;

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView

                DeviceBT deviceItem = new DeviceBT(mIndex,device.getName(),device.getAddress());

                mItems.add(deviceItem);

                mIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    return mItems;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onListFragmentInteraction(DeviceBT item);
}
```

}

Comment: Does your `Activity` implements `OnFragmentInteractionListener`? Please show full source code of Activity and Fragment

Comment: Yes! I posted a code.

Comment: Ok I corrected my post, sorry!